# SQL:How to get the data from a file based on a certain character pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a data file where I bulk insert data into my staging table.

This file has a sequence like that on certain lines.

> 0123456789   0122580000  2017092   2017092    300,000.00       10,000.00

..........

> 1527856778   6189580009  2017092   2015092    200,000.00       20,000.00

I did a bulk insert into a table already.

I need to insert certain data from that file into a temp table, so it has

the following records:

1. File date which is a sequence 2015091 where 2017 is a year, 91 is a day of the year.

   I have this logic to get a date:

   ```
   select dateadd(day, ltrim(rtrim(right('2017092',3))) - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(left('2017092',4) + 0, 1 ,1))
   ```

But that does not work, when I change '2017092' to [Data] - the column name from the table where I did bulk insert:

```
select dateadd(day,right(ltrim(rtrim(substring([Data],34,15))),3) - 1, DATEFROMPARTS(left(substring([Data],34,15),4) + 0, 1, 1)) from Staging_Table
where ltrim(rtrim(substring([Data],42,5))) = '92'
```

That query gives me `0002-04-02` instead of `2017-04-02`

2. Total amounts as a sum of dollar amounts at the same position on each line:

So, when insert is finished I have the following in my staging table:

```
Date           Total1        Total2
2015-04-02    500,000,00    30,000,00
```

Basically, I need to get a sum of all dollar amounts grouped by date.

How can I do something like that?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You should be loading the file into a table and then executing a query on the table to get the summary that you want.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Your statement is product specific.)

Comment: Yes, basically, I loaded data from the file into a table. Now I need to get the correct line with , for example, 2017091 sequence. SO, I need to take the line with `91`, convert `2017091` to `2017-04-02` based on a year and the day number, which I already do. Then, I just need to group the data, I think, by the date and get the Sum of dollar amounts

Comment: check that substring(Data, 34,15) is returning what you think it is

Comment: Yes, it does. When I do `select substring([data],34,15) from  Staging_Table where ltrim(rtrim(substring([Data],42,5))) = '92'`, it does return `2017092`

Comment: I just noticed you are not doing ltrim rtrim in the DATEFROMPARTS, and the dates are not in position 34 in the example data you posted, leading me to believe there might be extra spaces

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming you are loading you data as a string into one field `SomeCol`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('0123456789 0122580000 2017092 2017092 300,000.00 10,000.00'),
('1527856778 6189580009 2017092 2015092 200,000.00 20,000.00')

Select Date   = DateAdd(DAY,right(Pos3,3)-1,left(Pos3,4)+'0101')
      ,Total1 = sum(try_convert(money,Pos5))
      ,Total2 = sum(try_convert(money,Pos6))
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(100)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(100)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.SomeCol,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
 Group By Pos3
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Total1      Total2
2017-04-02  500000.00   30000.00
```